# Convert a vector containing binary values to double precision in matlab?

Tags: matlab, casting

I want to pass an input vector to the spectrogram function in MATLAB, but it returns the following error:

```
Error using spectrogram>chkinput (line 201)
The input signal X must be a double-precision vector.
Error in spectrogram (line 112)
chkinput(x);
```

Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by "binary values" MATLAB has no binary type. Please give an example of your input. Is it a string? A vector of doubles or logicals?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use the `double()` cast.

```
DoubleVector=double(BinaryVector);
```

In this manner, if `BinaryVector` is logical (type `class(BinaryVector)` to check this out), `DoubleVector` will still contain 1s and 0s, but in double precision, so you can feed it to `spectrogram()`.